# Perl: Extract data from different sections of a text file simultaneously

Tags: string, perl

I want to extract data from different sections of a text file simultaneously. Is it possible to open the file using two separate filehandles(as shown below) ? Or is it possible to cache the location of the first file handle and then return to that point in the document when I close the second one?

Note: I am only reading data from the text file, never writing to it.

```
open( $filehandle, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename )
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
$row = <$filehandle>;
{
    replace_unicode_char();
    if ( $row =~ /$table_num/ ) {
        open( $filehandle_reg, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename )
            or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
        $line = <$filehandle_reg>;
        if ( $line =~ /Section\_[0-9]+/ ) {
            # Do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the file isn't too big, you can store it in a string or an array.

Comment: This is out of the question as the file contains 102K lines...

Comment: That's only what, about 10MB? But yes, you can open a file twice as two different filehandles, and use them separately - it'll get a bit messy if there's writes going on though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `seek()` function to move around in the file, and the `tell()` function to get the current position in the file.

So, instead of having two filehandles, have two variables storing a position in the file, and use `seek()` to jump back and forth between them.

Comment: Thanks Richard... The tell() and seek() functions worked perfectly for me .